# Splinter Python Script Button Click

Tags: python, selenium, splinter

I am trying to write a code which lets me select the gender of my choice (let's use female as an example). The element as below. Please note that the ID keep changes so I cannot use css selector with the ID.

Please advise which method to use in selenium.

Thanks!

```
<div id="557f72b0-c612-428a-a77e-eb0841869ddb" class="nike-unite-gender-buttons gender nike-unite-component">
    <div class="shim"></div>
    <div class="error"></div>

    <input type="hidden" id="40d664f0-e498-4fa2-8a6f-7d9fc75cfe01" value="" name="gender" data-componentname="gender">

    <ul data-componentname="gender">

    <li id="222f5bc2-171e-450e-8182-8e15c8d9f47b" class="">
    <input type="button">
    <span>Male</span>
    </li>

    <li id="6c6098bb-fc9f-497e-8551-0ae6bb8a235c" class="">
    <input type="button">
    <span>Female</span>
    <</li>

    </ul>
    <div class="tip">Please select a gender.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try to use `XPath` selector, eg `//span[text='Female']`? Show your attempts and exception logs

Comment: @Andersson did you mean `text()`? :) By the way, in `splinter` there is that convenient `find_by_text()` shortcut.

Comment: Oh.. Yep, I mean `//span[text()='Female']`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, locate the gender container by the class names:

```
gender_container = browser.find_by_css('.nike-unite-gender-buttons.gender').first
```

Then, locate the button by the following text inside the `span` element:

```
female = gender_container.find_by_xpath('.//li[span = "Female"]/input').first
female.click()
```

---

Or, you may try finding the element *by text* directly:

```
browser.find_by_text('Female').first.click()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. it worked, i tried everything but find_by_text method. LOL..

Comment: @xBillBillx, you might [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem